# Chebyhev polynomials and Primality Testing

Tags: elementary-number-theory, primality-test, chebyshev-polynomials

It is a well known Theorem that an odd positive integer $n$ is prime if and only if
$T_{n}(x) \equiv x^n \pmod{n}$, where $T_{n}(x)$ is the $n^{th}$ Chebyshev polynomial of the first kind.

Do we deduce from this Theorem that $n$ is prime if and only if $T_{n}(x) \equiv x \pmod{x^{n-1} -1,n}$?

Any help with this will be appreciated.

PS. Please let me know if this is a duplicate. If so, will be happy to cancel.

Comment: Sorry what does it mean $\equiv x \pmod{x^{n-1} -1,n}$? I mean having 2 modulus?

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/286304/chebyshev-polynomials-of-the-first-kind-and-primality-testing

Comment: @Gevorg Hmayakyan: $f(x)  \pmod {g(x), n}$  ==> remainder($f(x), g(x)$) modulo $n$.

Answer (score 0):

In order to prove $\Longrightarrow$, I tried the following.
If $n$ is prime then
\begin{eqnarray*}
T_{n}(x) &\equiv & x^n \pmod{n}, \\
& \equiv & x(x^{n-1} -1) + x ,\\
T_{n}(x) &\equiv & x \pmod{x^{n-1} -1,n}.\
\end{eqnarray*}